# Signalr stock sample manipulation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr, jquery-ui-tabs, single-page-application

I have downloaded [SignalR Sample](https://nuget.org/packages/SignalR.Sample) and tested it. It works like a charm. For testing purposes I have created a new mvc 4 application using single page template and added a partial view that contains the html of StockTicker.html in the sample. I'm loading this partial view dynamically as one of the tab of a jquery ui tabs. I added the other required files too.

When I debug the application I see that the below script that can be found in SignalR.StockTicker.js file works before the view loaded.

```
$.connection.hub.start()
    .pipe(init)
    .pipe(function () {
        return ticker.server.getMarketState();
    })
    .done(function (state) {
        if (state === 'Open') {
            ticker.client.marketOpened();
        } else {
            ticker.client.marketClosed();
        }

        // Wire up the buttons
        $("#open").click(function () {
            ticker.server.openMarket();
        });

        $("#close").click(function () {
            ticker.server.closeMarket();
        });

        $("#reset").click(function () {
            ticker.server.reset();
        });
    });
```

So the function init can not do the dom manipulation that it has to do.

```
function init() {
    return ticker.server.getAllStocks().done(function (stocks) {
        $stockTableBody.empty();
        $stockTickerUl.empty();
        $.each(stocks, function () {
            var stock = formatStock(this);
            $stockTableBody.append(rowTemplate.supplant(stock));
            $stockTickerUl.append(liTemplate.supplant(stock));
        });
    });
}
```

What do I have to do to make my code work properly? [Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12816287/SpaFirst.rar) you can find my test project.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I added a link to my test project. You can find it at the end of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use jQuery UI Tabs' [load](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-load) event instead of document ready for this (because tab content is loaded asynchronously *after* document ready fires). Modify your code like this:

1. Add some sort of identification to your 'Forex' tab (like `<li id="forex"><a href="/Forex">Forex</a></li>`)
2. Change `$(function(){//init code here})` inside your 'SignalR.StockTicker.js' to a function that you can call yourself (I called it `initStockTicker`):

   ```
   $(function () {
       var ticker = $.connection.stockTicker, // the generated client-side hub proxy
       ...
   });
   ```

   =>

   ```
   function initStockTicker () {
       var ticker = $.connection.stockTicker, // the generated client-side hub proxy
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Add `load` handler to your tabs initialization:

   ```
   $("#marketWatchTabs").tabs({
       load: function (event, ui) {
           if (ui.tab.is("#forex")) {
               initStockTicker();
           }
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: But my partial view containing the html of StockTicker.html is loading dynamically after the container view loaded.

Comment: Can you post more bits of code then please? What _exactly_ does not work?

Comment: You probably want to call everything from `SignalR.StockTicker.js`'s `$(function() {...})` after you dynamically load the tab content. In your case if would probably mean having a sort of `init` function that contains everything from `SignalR.StockTicker.js` and call it on [load](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-load) event in jQuery UI's Tab.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the idea. But how can I change 'SignalR.StockTicker.js' to a function?